# How Can I Clone a tab in a JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, clone, jtabbedpane

I'm looking for a way to clone (duplicate) a whole tab (the selected one) in a `JTabbedPane`. Every time I take the tabwith `getSelectedComponent()` and add it to the pane, the title of the tab disapnö rs and I get no second tab. But there is no exception.

I tried to copy the currently selected tab. Each tab is a `JPanel` with a simple `JTable` on it and I want to get the selected tab two times.

Comment: So you want to clone the jpanel ? But when data changes in the jtable also reflect in the duplicate?

Comment: No, just an isolate copy of the panel (the selected tab) which is finally shown as a second tab in the tabbedpane

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the same swing component can't appear in multiple places in your GUI, so you would actually have to create new instances of all your UI elements for the "copied" tab and set their values to the same values of the first tab / connect them to the same domain objects.

Comment: I solved it now with a tmp-file... Writing the data to it and create a New tab and add the data in a second tab... In my opinion not the Best solution, but it works . Thx 4 help =)

Comment: Why use a tmp file? Why not just read the content from the GUI elements in the first tab and put it in the components in the second tab?

Answer (score 0):

In Swings, a component can be added to only one container. Adding it again to another container will have no effect.